# How to force the content of row+1 cell with jet Essentials addin?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm using Jet essentiels excel add'in to build reports with data coming from a database. 
This is the final result I want to get : 
if resource id of line 2 is = to resource id of line 3, then 0, otherwise, resource id of line 2. (if(A2=A3;0;A2)

but when I run Jet report, additional lines are created, my formula is changed to: if(A2=**A10**;0;A2)

any idea of how to force the cell of row A+1 in the design mode?
thanks in advance